# Using Spring IDE in Eclipse 3.4

Tags: eclipse-3.4, spring-webflow-2

I'm using the Spring IDE plugin with Eclipse 3.4 (finally decided to upgrade), and I have several projects which use the Webflow integration that comes with the Spring IDE plugin.  For some reason, I can't view anything having to do with Spring Webflow in Eclipse 3.4.  It worked just fine in 3.3, but not 3.4.  Has anybody encountered this problem before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up just re-installing Eclipse and all its plugins and it just worked.  I have no idea what the problem was, but I'm guessing it's probably related to me not having the proper version of one or more of Spring IDEs dependencies installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try removing/adding Spring nature to those projects ? Sometimes it helps when upgrading. By the way, doesn't have any problem on my 3.4.

Comment: Hi Olivier,
Yes, I tried that, but it didn't work.  I suspect I may have been just missing a library, because I re-downloaded the latest J2EE version of Eclipse and reinstalled all the plugins and it worked fine.  Thank you for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest downloading's SpringSource's own distribution of Eclipse. It's comes pre-bundled with Spring IDE and few other spring'related features.

I've always found the installation and upgrading of Spring IDE to be problematic; whether it's the fault of Eclipse or the plugin itself I can't say.